# jQuery Mobile Popup not firing properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

As I am finishing a Responsive Web with jQuery Mobile and PHP, I am now prettifying some data transitions and popups.

**I am now facing 2 problems: (The first one is solved)**

I have a "ShowMessage" functions that will show a specified messages and a redirect URL. Once the user clicks "OK" button, it will be redirected.

The PHP itself works perfectly but not the jQuery Mobile. What will the PHP do is to transferring some messages and a URL into a PHP file called showmessage.php. Then showmessage.php will handle the message and URL then output as normal HTML with CSS and JS.

When PHP finishes his job, the page is going to be displayed. I have tested 4 types of Browsers (mainly Chrome and Safari because the site is for Mobile Device users, those are mainly used browsers). Chrome works as expected (although a little bit displaced but I will try to figure it out) and Safari didn't.

The HTML in showmessage is using a "POPUP" feature from jQuery Mobile, in normal circumstances, the page will automatically popup and show the dialog box and a "OK" button. After the user clicks the "OK" button it will be redirected.

**For Safari, I can see the dialog comes out for about 0.1 seconds and the dialog disappeared and it leaves a blank page.**

I only implemented the following code for my HTML:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#infoMsg", function () {
    $('#infoMsgPopup').popup('open');
});
```

You can view it in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6j4evbr/2/
(Please don't tell me you see the code works **as you are not using Safari**)

The above question was solved by a comment

---

The following question is remaining unsolved.

OK, the second problems is:
I have a navigation bar in the footer. The left side is a button to the home page and the right side is to log people out.

When the people clicks "Logout", it will pop out a message (I admit I love using POPUP because Mobile Devices love it) and ask the using "Are you sure to logout?" with two buttons "Yes" and "No". If the user clicks "No", it returns to the screen, if the user clicks "Yes", the system will log the user out.

```
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php?p=main" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="home">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#logoutMsgPop" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" data-icon="power">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logoutMsgPop" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" data-history="false" style="max-width: 480px;">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3 style="margin-top: -1em;">Logout</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p align="center" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">Are you sure to Logout?</p>
            <p align="center">
                <a href="index.php?p=logout" class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse">Yes</a>
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline" data-rel="back">No</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know if the issue is related to the URL or not.

Actually almost every links are followed by a question mark "?" (for example: index.php?page=main) and if I clicked #logoutMsg (The link will popups a dialog), sometimes it fails. I have no idea why it fires sometimes and not fires sometimes, I am here for a solution.

Thank you very much. I hope not much of you think this is TL;DR.

Comment: For the first problem, maybe use the pagecontainer widget's show event and add a small delay before launching the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/m6j4evbr/3/

Comment: Thank you for your help but no effect on Safari.

Comment: Disregard, showmessage works, thanks!